# getting json data from localhost to use in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I'm creating a D3 bubble chart, using json data. I'm using sinatra for my app, and my json data is available at localhost:4567/data.json

I tried using

```
var myData = [];
$.get('data.json', function(data) {
  myData = data;
  console.log(myData);
.......
```

and I get the correct values in the javascript console, but the bubble chart does not render. (The rest of the code works if I copy and paste the data from 'data.json' and set it to a var, but it does not work if I use the $get method).

Do you have any ideas on how I could access this json data from localhost:4567?

Much appreciated,

Tim

Answer (score 1):

I think what is probably going on is that jquery isn't automatically parsing the data as a JSON object due to missing MIME headers in the response from your server. Try using getJSON instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use 
    d3.json('data.json', function(data) {
    myData = data;
    console.log(myData);
    .......

to read the json file